# loading bar is not displaying in chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

i want to show a loading bar when i click in to my paginator link.
  the paginator goes through a ajax function. when i use mozila it shows the loading bar.
  but when i using chrome,safari it doesn't showing the loading bar

my loading bar is a div and this present in my index.php file.

```
<div class="loading_wrapper" id="loading_wrapper" style="display:none;">
<div class="load_animation"><img src="/magsonwink/images/loadinfo.gif" width="24" height="24" /></div>
<div class="load_texts"><h4>Loading...</h4></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

the paginator links also present in index.php file. when i click the paginator link this goes to the function

```
    var resp_msg =
            $.ajax({
                url: path + set_page,
                async: false,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#loading_wrapper').show();
                },
                success: function(data, result) {
                if (!result)
                    alert('Failure to set the value.');
                }
            }).responseText;

if (resp_msg) {

    $('#loading_wrapper').hide();
    $(objReplace).html(resp_msg);
 }
```

this working fine in mozila but doesni't in chrome.
     there is no error displaying when i look at the error console
     .please help me.
     thanks in advance

Comment: Is the data actually being loaded? If so, this might be a CSS issue rather than Javascript/jQuery...

Comment: thanks, in this case when i add a alert() after ' $('#loading_wrapper').show();' then the loading bar is showed to me.

Comment: At a guess it could be that Chrome is getting the `resp_msg` back before it gets a chance to show the `loading_wrapper`... is the document you're requesting on the same domain as the page you're requesting it from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is "async" set to "false". Setting the property to "true" should fix the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var resp_msg =
        $.ajax({
            url: path + set_page,
            async: false,
            beforeSend: showloader() ,
            success: function(data, result) {
            if (!result)
                alert('Failure to set the value.');
            }
        }).responseText;

if (resp_msg) {

$('#loading_wrapper').hide();
$(objReplace).html(resp_msg);}


function showloader(){  $('#loading_wrapper').show();  }
```

Comment: I think beforeSend is getting called before loading the loading_wrapper div.Have you added this code in document.ready()

Answer (score 0):

Have you measured the time of response? Is it coming too fast? Chrome and IE take more time for rendering the image compared to Firefox. It may be happening that your image hide/show may not be getting sufficient time for rendering. Check this by applying some delay, you may be able to see the image in Chrome and IE too